# Simple Video Renderer for AVI/yuv420p/pcm stream?

Tags: .net, video, libvlc

I am capturing video and audio from a capture card with ffmpeg and piping that out as an avi stream with yuv420p video and pcm audio.

I want to take that 1 stream and send it to a simple video renderer and also send it to a second instance of ffmpeg to be encoded and streamed.

Ironically the 1st and 3rd part are the easy part, decoding video and what-not since ffmpeg is so versatile. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to render that avi stream in a .net wpf or windows forms application without becoming an expert at writing directshow filter graphs and the likes.

Any ideas?

Seems like the VLC control would be useful, but I don't seem to be able to feed it with stdin.

Comment: With Qt this task is pretty easy. Are you ready to use Qt?

Comment: Yeah, I think I'd be willing to use Qt

Comment: Then you could look https://github.com/RSATom/QmlVideoProducer (sorry for russian comments, it was written for article in one russian online magazine)

Comment: And that's example https://github.com/RSATom/QmlVlc/blob/master/QmlVlcMmVideoOutput.cpp#L89 how you could make QVideoFrame from "I420" (in terms of libvlc) frame